# "across" and "through"

Tags: prepositions

[image: Image A touches B touches the wall]

I described the situation shown in the image as follows:

> The object A is pressed against the wall across/through the object B.

Could you advise me on which of "across" and "through" is better.

Comment: Definitely use _through_; I think that conveys the meaning much better.

Comment: I guess if I had to use one, it would be *through* but really I wouldn't say "A is pressed against the wall" at all.  A is pressed against B, which is pressed against the wall.